# two nested for loops on a list

Tags: for-loop, arraylist

how to create two nested for loops on elements of a list such that the second loop starts on elements after the first loop. For example I know how to to it on range():

```
    for i in range(0,3):
       for j in range(i+1,3):
           print([i,j])
```

what if I have a list A=[1,4,7,3] instead of range(0,3) and I want to do the same thing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you please elaborate more by examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `len()` method.

```
for i in range(0, len(listA)):
   for j in range(i+1,len(listA)):
       print(listA[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate() apart from range as well. Try this code :

```
for indexValue,sub_list1 in enumerate(array):


 for sub_list2 in array[indexValue+1:]:


    print(sub_list2)
```