# Two loop with restriction [1,2] and [2,1] not acceptable python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have two for loop to select items from a list and don't want to repeat `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` similar is the case for other elements. Basically I have

```
for i in range(0,20):
    for j in range(0,20):
        if (i != j):
            function(list[i],list[j])
```

The output from `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` gives the same results and I don't want to repeat that. basically i and j are identical array. I eliminate similar elements using if loop.And I want to eliminate repeated elements.

Comment: Don’t have the second loop count from 0. count from i + 1.

Comment: Do not name your variables `list` - you shadow the built in `list()` with it

Comment: mistermiyagi it works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply start your j loop from i.

```
lis = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(i + 1, 5):
        lis.append([i, j])
```

This outputs

```
[[0, 1],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 3],
 [0, 4],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 4]]
```

For a smaller output, I changed 20 to 5.

Comment: I think it should be i+1 otherwise i=j answer is here i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58761001/two-nested-for-loops-on-a-list

Comment: Yes, I focussed on the [1, 2] and [2, 1] part, and forgot about the equality. It should be i+1. Thanks for pointing out.